# React native, Unable to resolve module for static image

Tags: android, image, react-native, packager

I'm using react-native 0.14.1

```
react-native run-android

[3:10:56 PM] <START> find dependencies
Unable to resolve module image!ic_action_android_back_white3 from /Users/lion/Desktop/Developer/AwesomeProject/NewTrackActivity.js
Unable to resolve module image!ic_action_android_back_white3 from /Users/lion/Desktop/Developer/AwesomeProject/NewTrackActivity.js
```

If I force open my app in Genymotion it can't find my image.

> Requiring unknown module image!ic_action_android_back_white3

I'm tried to move image to both `./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxx` and `./assets/drawable-xxx` but neither work.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430875/how-to-import-file-from-outside-components-in-react/60505792#60505792) worked! for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried to mount the image, like the new asset manager allows you to do? It's described in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html).

Use the following prop for the Image component. Choose the right **relative path** and dont forget the **extension**.

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

Comment: I've tried it. It's always work. But I'm very suspicious to my case.
What's the difference between this method & image! ?

Comment: The [new asset manager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3545) allows you to add images **on the fly** without rebuilding your whole project.
`1. Same system on iOS and Android.` and also `5. Adding and changing images doesn't require app recompilation, just refresh the simulator as you normally do.` ([Official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html))

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes, your image might include an `@2x` or `@3x` for different screen dpi as mentioned in [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources). In such case the path should specify the image name without the `@2x` or `@3x` suffix. For example if image file name is `img@2x.png`:

```
<Image source={require('./img.png')} />
```

Answer (score 7):

Restart your react packager. That worked for me.

Comment: That's not work for me
I've also tried to build bundle by

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.android.js   --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle   --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

but still doesn't work.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a running React packager won't pick up new directories/resource paths that you've added to your project that would otherwise be picked up if you restarted the packager i.e. a running packager won't pick up if you add `./img/favicon.png` but if you restart the packager it will add `./img` and any subsequent files added there will be picked up on reloads without restart of the packager.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an issue of adding assets after your initial build.

I closed the emulator and bundler, cleared cache and ran RN - run-ios/run-andriod - and then not a problem.

I was also wondering if just running link might work, but did not get to test this.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your image in that folder itself instead of saving in asset folder and give path as :

```
<Image source={require('../download.png')} />
```

It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error message *Unable to resolve module* for files with **upper case characters**.

My solution - rename file names to **lower case**.

Using in code:

```
<Image source={require('../download.png')} />
```

Versions:
*react native - 0.62*
*expo - 38*