# How to import file from outside /components in react

Tags: reactjs

My folder structure is as follows:

[image]

In my App.Js (which is under the components folder), I have:

```
import variables from '/src/EnvVariables/variables.json';
```

However, I get an error:

```
You attempted to import /src/EnvVariables/variables.json which falls
outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of
src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or
add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

I have also tried:

```
import variables from './src/EnvVariables/variables.json';
import variables from '/src/EnvVariables/variables.json';
import variables from '/src/EnvVariables/variables.json';
import variables from '/EnvVariables/variables.json';
import variables from './EnvVariables/variables.json';
```

All either give the above error, or say "can't resolve file".

This file is in a folder that is under /src, as they said. But it still tells me it must be under the /src/ directory. How can I import my variables.json file? I don't want to just put it under "components", i prefer to better organize it.

Comment: Are you using webpack, can you add that file in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to import with the relative path? (with one or more `../` sections)

```
import variables from "../EnvVariables/variables.json"
```

Of course, if you prefer absolute paths you can setup https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/, but I believe for first, you should try the first solution

Answer (score 2):

Do `../../` before path

```
source={require('../../assets/eating.png')}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to import your any file to a component : (just follow this steps)

1. Simply you can create a `.env` file in `src` directory .
2. In that `.env` file you need to add this line only `NODE_PATH = src/`
3. Then you can write `import "Home.css"` (your file name will be here) to a component from `src`, it will take it easily.
4. Run the program again , then you will get the same error, but take
   it easy and just you have to do fully start your program with the `npm start` from
   a new terminal.